# Shift my x-axis in time (hours) in ggplot2

Tags: r, timeshift

I am creating a heatmap with overlaid points for sunrise and sunset in ggplot2, with hour of the day on the x axis and the day of the year on the y. The figure looks how I want it, but I'd like to shift my x axis so that it starts at 07:00 and ends at 06:00 to better capture the day/night shift and place the daylight hours in the middle of the plot.

I'd like to avoid restructuring my data, but I can't figure out how to shift my x axis 7 hours ahead.

Below is my data and the code I am using to generate the heatmap and overlaid sunrise/sunset (really just a tile plot with overlaid points).

data:

[MB_tile](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qt_PHyBQ8OUMmQfb1NEt8ih04MYTkFxkRA0CzchxOew/edit#gid=494561889)
[sunrise_setMB](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19v82MI9KtQCMI5Kaqk8Tjw-FvcKhCrTc6JlH_S06qtY/edit#gid=1721196505)

```
MB_tile <- readr::read_csv('MB/MB_all_nonsong_tile.csv')
sunrise_setMB <- readr::read_csv('MB/MB_rise_set2.csv')

 ggplot()+
  geom_tile(data =MB_tile,aes(x=Time, y = as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"),fill=Value), show.legend=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'black')+
  geom_point(data = sunrise_setMB, aes(x=rise_set, y=as.Date(days,format="%m/%d/%Y"),color = label),show.legend=FALSE)+
  ggtitle("MB Presence")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  xlab('Time') + ylab('Date')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to set a random day to the time (January 1st 2024). If the time is before 7:00, add a day. So all the data is between 2024-01-01 07:00 and 2024-01-02 06:59:59. You can control the labels on the x-axis with `scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")`, so no date will be we displayed.

```
library(tidyverse)

MB_tile <- readr::read_csv('MB/MB_all_nonsong_tile.csv')
sunrise_setMB <- readr::read_csv('MB/MB_rise_set2.csv')

MB_tile2 = MB_tile %>% 
  mutate( daytime=  ymd_hms(paste0("2024-01-01", " ", Time))  ) %>% 
  mutate(daytime_offset   =  if_else(hour(daytime) < 7,  daytime + days(1), daytime  ))

sunrise_setMB2 = sunrise_setMB %>% 
  mutate( daytime=  ymd_hms(paste0("2024-01-01", " ", rise_set))  ) %>% 
  mutate(daytime_offset   =  if_else(hour(daytime) < 7,  daytime + days(1), daytime  ))

ggplot()+
  geom_tile(data =MB_tile2,aes(x=daytime_offset, y = as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"),fill=Value), show.legend=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'black')+
  geom_point(data = sunrise_setMB2, aes(x=daytime_offset, y=as.Date(days,format="%m/%d/%Y"),color = label),show.legend=FALSE)+
  ggtitle("MB Presence")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  xlab('Time') + ylab('Date')+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Lubridate is a core member of the tidyverse 2.0.0 [tidyverse blog](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/03/tidyverse-2-0-0/).

I also tried modular maths but I got confused. I will read your answer.

Comment: Ah, missed have missed that in the last update. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A similar solution to Vince here, except I would use modular math and get the time difference in hours. Also, it's important that your NA fill value is not misinterpreted as a value on your gradient, and you would do better with `geom_path` for sunrise / sunset lines.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bg <- MB_tile %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         baseline = as.POSIXct("2024-01-01"),
         Time = as.POSIXct(paste("2024-01-01", Time), 
                           format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"),
         Time = (as.numeric(difftime(Time, baseline, units = "h")) - 7) %% 24)

fg <- sunrise_setMB %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(days, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         base = as.POSIXct("2024-01-01"),
         rise_set = as.POSIXct(paste("2024-01-01", rise_set), 
                               format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"),
         Time = (as.numeric(difftime(rise_set, base, units = "h")) - 7) %% 24)

ggplot(bg, aes(Time, Date)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'gray20', na.value = "cornsilk") +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("orange", "orangered")) +
  geom_path(data = fg, aes(color = label), linewidth = 1.5) +
  ggtitle("MB Presence") +
  scale_x_continuous("Time", labels = ~sprintf("%02d:00", (.x + 7) %% 24),
                     breaks = seq(0, 24, 3)) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 20) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  ylab('Date') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

There are probably too many tiles on the y axis to see them all in a standard plotting window. You may get a better idea of the annual pattern by averaging each hour of the year:

```r
bg <- MB_tile %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         baseline = as.POSIXct("2024-01-01"),
         Time = as.POSIXct(paste("2024-01-01", Time), 
                           format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"),
         Time = (as.numeric(difftime(Time, baseline, units = "h")) - 7) %% 24,
         Time = floor(Time),
         yday = lubridate::yday(Date)) %>%
  group_by(yday, Time) %>%
  summarise(Value = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(yday = as.Date("2023-12-31") + yday)

fg <- sunrise_setMB %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(days, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         base = as.POSIXct("2024-01-01"),
         rise_set = as.POSIXct(paste("2024-01-01", rise_set), 
                               format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"),
         Time = (as.numeric(difftime(rise_set, base, units = "h")) - 7) %% 24,
         yday = lubridate::yday(Date)) %>%
  group_by(yday, label) %>%
  summarise(Time = mean(Time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(yday = as.Date("2023-12-31") + yday)

ggplot(bg, aes(Time, yday)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Value), interpolate = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'gray20', na.value = "cornsilk") +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("orange", "orangered")) +
  geom_path(data = fg, aes(color = label), linewidth = 1.5) +
  ggtitle("MB Presence, averaged hourly observations 2018-2022") +
  scale_x_continuous("Time", labels = ~sprintf("%02d:00", (.x + 7) %% 24),
                     breaks = seq(0, 24, 3)) +
  scale_y_date("Time of year", date_labels = "%B", date_breaks = "month") +
  theme_gray(base_size = 20) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  ylab('Date') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Congrats. The key seems to substract 7 hours to the dataset  and `%%24` while adding 7 hours (with `%%24`) on the x-axis . I was missing this point when I tried. This answer repesct the logic of having a pure time x-axis.   (While mine was to hide a date-time axis as a time axis)

Comment: It's actually a relabelled continuous axis @VinceGreg - faked with `sprintf` and reversing the modular math part.

Comment: Thank you! I need to display the data without averaging, but the average hourly value over the timeseries is a very interesting plot. Appreciate the insightful answer.